# Multiple forms, same action but not at the same timing

Tags: php, html, forms, function

I have a page that allows a user to change the images directly. Every image is changable so therefor the type of form for that certain image has a same type of construction: as followed below

```
function genForm($id, $name, $ex, $mapRef, $formID) 
{
    echo "<form id='imgForm' action='{$mapRef}exe/uploadImg.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>"
            . "<label class='custom-file-upload'> "
            . "<input type='file' id='imgFile' name='imgFile'/>Selecteer andere foto</label>"
            . "<input type='hidden' name='ID' value='{$id}'/>"
            . "<input type='hidden' name='orgFilename' value='{$name}'/>"
            . "<input type='hidden' name='fileExt' value='{$ex}'/>"
            . "<input type='hidden' name='fileLoc' value='{$mapRef}'/></form>";
}
```

Only one form shall be submitted once the image-change is done.

But only the first form works now, and if I delete that first form then the second one works, etc.

I tried working with dynamic form-id's but this did not change anything.

Am I not allowed to have multiple forms with the same action-type at one page?

[first form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MovJw.png) 
[Second form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq0i1.png)

Comment: the id attribute in html is unique, so if you print this form multiple times it might not work, you can have as many forms as you want on 1 page. Could you provide us with the html output of say at least 2 of them, might clarify it a bit.

Comment: Sure thing, will do, one moment

Comment: I have uploaded the images of the first and second form, the first works the second does not. As said, if I delete the first the second will work

Comment: `{$mapRef}` seems not to work at all, the url is the same in both. and because of that fileLoc is also empty

Comment: This is the index-page $mapRef is therefor given a -null-  parameter. But as I said the first form works so it is not because of that.

Comment: In your form images, there is no input with type 'file'. All the paras are hidden only.

Comment: But then why does one exact same form work, but the others don't?